# Why users cannot be deleted in salesforce?

Tags: user-management

Why users cannot be deleted in salesforce? As a lot of junk data will available in database as inactive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to maintain historical records of who did what, users are never deleted in salesforce.com.

Even deactivated users name will be listed in "Created By" fields in all Objects.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reasons I can think of is for audit purposes. Keeping the users in the system is a way to ensure that you know who did what.